Why am I getting a client side error when trying to submit a file uploaded through a form? (using React, TypeScript, Nextjs)
I've created an edit form modal client side component. The form is populated with event data that you can update. Everything is being able to properly update in the server, but when I try and add a new file (photo) to be updated, it's not even making it to the server before throwing an error. I wrapped the async call in a try/catch, but i'm not understanding the error message.
I'm using a form that accepts a clientAction function.
Here is the image upload input
 <div className="mb-4">
  <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Image Upload</label>
  <input type="file" 
         name="image_url" 
         accept="images/*" 
         key={inputKey} 
         onChange={handleFileChange} 
         className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-     tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" />
    {error && <div style={{color: 'red'}}>{error}</div>}
 </div>

Here is handleFileChange method for input:
const handleFileChange = (event: any) => {
    const files = event.target.files;

    if (files) {
      const uploadedFile = files[0];
      const fileExtention = uploadedFile.name.split(".").pop()?.toLocaleLowerCase();

      if (fileExtention === 'heic' || fileExtention === 'heif') {
        setInputKey(Date.now());
        setError('HEIC/HEIF images are not supported. Please upload a different file.')
        setFile(null)
      } else {
        setError(null)
        setFile(uploadedFile)
      }
    }
  }


Here is the clientAction method:
const clientAction = async (formData: FormData) => {
    let formDate = formData.get("date") as string;
    const newDate = formDate.length > 1 ? new Date(formData.get("date") as unknown as Date) : eventData.date
    const newImg = file as File;

    const img = newImg && newImg.size ? newImg : formValues["image_url"]

    const updatedEvent = {
        title: formData.get("title") as string,
        date: newDate,
        doors_open: newDoorsOpenTime !== null ? newDoorsOpenTime : formData.get("doors_open") as string,
        start_time:  newStartTime !== null ? newStartTime : formData.get("start_time") as string,
        description: formData.get("description") as string,
        venue_name: formData.get("venue_name") as string,
        address: formData.get("address") as string,
        image_url: img,
        ticket_link: formData.get("ticket_link") as string,
        ticket_price: formData.get("ticket_price") as string,
    }

    try {
      const response = await updateCurrentUserEvent(updatedEvent, eventData.id)
      if (response?.error) {
        console.log("ERROR!!!!")
        toast.error(response.error)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("ERROR!", error)
    }
  } 

Here is my updateCurrentUserEvent server method:
export async function updateCurrentUserEvent(eventData: any, eventId: number) {
  const currentEvent = await prisma.event.findUnique({
    where: { id: eventId }
  })

  let image_url: string | File | null = null
  let date; 

  // if there is no image uploaded
  // use the oringal image_url
  if (!(eventData["image_url"] as File).size) {
    if (currentEvent?.image_url) {
      image_url = currentEvent.image_url
    }
  } else {
    image_url = eventData["image_url"] as File
  }

  // if there is no date chosen,
  // use the original date
  if (!(eventData["date"])) {
    date = currentEvent?.date;
  }

  const convertedStartTime = to24HourFormat(eventData["start_time"] as string)
  const convertedDoorsOpen = to24HourFormat(eventData["doors_open"] as string)
  
  const newEvent = {
    title: eventData["title"] as string,
    date: date ? date : new Date(eventData["date"] as unknown as Date),
    doors_open: convertedDoorsOpen,
    start_time: convertedStartTime,
    description: eventData["description"] as string,
    venue_name: eventData["venue_name"] as string,
    address: eventData["address"] as string,
    image_url,
    ticket_link: eventData["ticket_link"] as string,
    ticket_price: eventData["ticket_price"] as string,
  }

  // valitdate eventData to find errors
  const result = EventSchema.safeParse(newEvent);

  if (!result.success) {
    let errorMessage = "";

    result.error.issues.forEach((issue) => {
      errorMessage = errorMessage + "•" + issue.message + "\n";
    })
    return {
      error: errorMessage
    }
  }

  // if data passed validation, take the uploaded file and 
  // upload to S3 to get url.
  try {
    const file = result.data["image_url"]
    let newImage_url;
    if (file instanceof File) {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(await file.arrayBuffer());
    newImage_url = await uploadFileToS3(buffer, file.name)
    } else {
      newImage_url = currentEvent?.image_url;
    }

    const newData = { ...result.data }

    await prisma.event.update({
      where: {
        id: eventId
      },
      data: {
        ...newData,
        image_url: newImage_url,
      }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("ERROR", error);
    return { error: "The was an error Updating your event"}
  }
}

Finally here is the error i'm getting in the console:
ERROR! undefined 
    app-index.js:33:21
    error app-index.js:33
    error hydration-error-info.js:45
    overrideMethod myshows:13441
    clientAction EditEventModal.tsx:116
    startHostTransition react-dom.development.js:12693
    startTransition react-dom.development.js:12590
    startHostTransition react-dom.development.js:12690
    submitForm react-dom.development.js:29444
    callCallback react-dom.development.js:20498
    invokeGuardedCallbackImpl react-dom.development.js:20547
    invokeGuardedCallback react-dom.development.js:20622
    invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError react-dom.development.js:20636
    executeDispatch react-dom.development.js:31986
    processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder react-dom.development.js:32018
    processDispatchQueue react-dom.development.js:32031
    dispatchEventsForPlugins react-dom.development.js:32042
    dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem react-dom.development.js:32232
    batchedUpdates$1 react-dom.development.js:24843
    batchedUpdates react-dom.development.js:28703
    dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem react-dom.development.js:32231
    dispatchEvent react-dom.development.js:29999
    dispatchDiscreteEvent react-dom.development.js:29970
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
    addEventBubbleListener react-dom.development.js:30219
    addTrappedEventListener react-dom.development.js:32135
    listenToNativeEvent react-dom.development.js:32074
    listenToAllSupportedEvents react-dom.development.js:32085
    listenToAllSupportedEvents react-dom.development.js:32080
    hydrateRoot$1 react-dom.development.js:37768
    hydrateRoot react-dom.development.js:38354
    hydrateRoot client.js:20
    hydrate app-index.js:248
    startTransition react.development.js:2661
    hydrate app-index.js:248
    <anonymous> app-next-dev.js:10
    appBootstrap app-bootstrap.js:57
    loadScriptsInSequence app-bootstrap.js:23
    appBootstrap app-bootstrap.js:56
    <anonymous> app-next-dev.js:8
    NextJS 7


Please excuse the hacky code, will clean up later, but really want to understand what's going on.
I also have a create event form that allows me to upload a photo without an issue using basically the same code.
Fwiw: I take the file, processes it on the server with sharp & S3, to save it as a URL string.
Thanks in advance!
I've tried to emulate what I’m doing in my create event form using the same logic to upload a file. I expected it to behave the same and at least make it to the server. But it's throwing errors before it makes it to the server.

update the question to include updateCurrentUserEvent implementation

@AhmedAbdelbaset Thank you for your response. I've updated with my updateCurrentUserEvent

Is it server action?

There is an unhandled error in updateCurrentUserEvent before the try statement. You have a lot of as ... there. you can double check this part by maybe console.log everything to figure out where it comes from. the try/catch outside the calling doesn't do anything because server actions don't throw any error. move the try/catch inside the function to wrap all the function body
